# matching 2 columns in 2 dataframes R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames:

```
frame1

First_Name  Last_Name 
John         Smith
Jane         Doe 
John         Doe

frame2

First_Name   Last_Name
John          Smith
Sally         Smith
Jane          Doe
```

I want to extract only rows where the First_Name and Last_Name columns match:

```
output:

First_Name    Last_Name
John            Smith
Jane            Doe
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `intersect` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(frame1, frame2)
#   First_Name Last_Name
#1       John     Smith
#2       Jane       Doe
```

Or `inner_join`

```
inner_join(frame1, frame2)
```

---

Or using `fintersect` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fintersect(setDT(frame1), setDT(frame2))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `merge`

```
merge(frame1, frame2)
```

#### data

```
frame1 <- structure(list(First_Name = c("John", "Jane", "John"), Last_Name = c("Smith", 
"Doe", "Doe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

frame2 <- structure(list(First_Name = c("John", "Sally", "Jane"), Last_Name = c("Smith", 
"Smith", "Doe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a `base R` solution with `Reduce`. Here the code:

Data:

```
#Data 1
frame1 <- structure(list(First_Name = c("John", "Jane", "John"), Last_Name = c("Smith", 
"Doe", "Doe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

#Data2
frame2 <- structure(list(First_Name = c("John", "Sally", "Jane"), Last_Name = c("Smith", 
"Smith", "Doe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

The code:

```
#Code
df <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,sort=F),x = list(frame1,frame2))
```

Output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name
1       John     Smith
2       Jane       Doe
```

Or just `merge()`:

```
#Code2
merge(frame1,frame2,sort=F)
```

Output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name
1       John     Smith
2       Jane       Doe
```